# In osmosis, how does chemical potential ever balance out?

Tags: physical-chemistry

Chemical poential is modeled by the equation $\mu_i = \mu_{i,0} + RT\ln x_i$.

If you have one side with some $x_i$ of NaCl and another side with pure water separated by a semipermeable membrane through which only water can pass, water will go through that membrane until the chemical potential is equal on both sides. My question is: How can it ever reach equilibrium if it's impossible for $x_i = 0 $ since there always is going to be some concentration of NaCl? Does water stop flowing because of the extra hydrostatic pressure? Is there an equation that can be used to determine how much volume of water will flow during osmosis given a certain set of conditions?

Comment: Yes, you must account for the pressure change in order to balance the chemical potentials, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osmotic_pressure#Derivation_of_the_van_.27t_Hoff_formula)